# How to display table information in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

The following code is supposed to display the Parts from the Inventory AllParts Observable List. I'm unsure if this is the inventory class not returning the correct object, or if there is something else going on, or if I'm missing something in the initialization of the Table.

edit: I'm expecting the `MainViewController` `initializer` to load the `PartId`, `PartName`, `PartStock`, and `PartPrice` through the `Inventory` class via the `observableList allParts` . The InHouse class Extends the Part class

> MainViewController

```java
package ViewController;

import Model.InHouse;
import Model.Inventory;
import Model.Part;
import Model.Product;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainViewController implements Initializable {


    private static Inventory inventory;

    //Part FXIDs
    @FXML private TableView<Part> PartsTable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Part, Integer> PartId;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Part, String> PartName;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Part, Integer> PartStock;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Part, Double> PartPrice;

    //sets up the table view and loads the parts from the inventory list
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        PartId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PartId"));
        PartName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PartName"));
        PartStock.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PartStock"));
        PartPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PartPrice"));

        inventory.addPart(new InHouse(0, "name", 5.00, 1, 1, 5, 0));

        PartsTable.setItems(inventory.getAllParts());
    }

}
```

> Inventory

```java
package Model;

public class Inventory {

    public final static ObservableList<Part> allParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void addPart(Part newPart){
        this.allParts.add(newPart);
    }

    public ObservableList<Part> getAllParts(){
        return this.allParts;
    }
}
```

> adding parts class

```java
public abstract class Part {

    private int id,
            stock,
            min,
            max;
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public Part(int id, String name, double price, int stock, int min, int max) {
        this.id = id;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


}
```

> error output

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/home/Projects/2019.08.03_C482/InventorySystem/dist/run1962514670/InventorySystem.jar!/ViewController/MainView.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at c482.C482.start(C482.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$10(GtkApplication.java:245)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ViewController.MainViewController.initialize(MainViewController.java:142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application c482.C482
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please include the desired behavior, and a specific problem or error, and please provide output.

Comment: [edit] your question and add code for class `Part`.

Comment: Are the `TableView`s and `TableColumns` classes implemented directly in the library, in which case imports should be provided, or is this a custom class, which should have shown code like @Abra stated?

Comment: @Abra Thank you, Ive added the Part's class.

Comment: @FailingCoder Thank you, I've added the behavior expectations and error output and I've included the imports. For the ```TableView``` and ```TableColumns``` are from the library

Comment: Post contents of file `MainView.fxml`

Comment: To sum up the suggestions from others: if you need debugging help (what went wrong, why doesn't my code do what I expect?) the best is to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem :) In your case that would be: controller, fxml, application, data class/es and error stacktrace. And always mind the _M_ - that is do not provide your production code, but an example that's written for the sole purpose of being an example :) Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: aside: you rarely want static access for fields ..

Comment: and last: the error is that you never instantiate the inventory - that's why you get a NPE when trying to add an item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the *javadoc* for class [PropertyValueFactory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html).
This line of your code (from class `MainViewController`)...

```java
PartId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PartId"));
```

implies that your class `Part` has the following declared method...

```java
public ObservableValue<Integer> PartIdProperty()
```

And note that the name is case-sensitive. In other words, `partIdProperty` is **not** correct. The same applies to each other `TableColumn`. From the code you posted, it looks like these methods are missing from your `Part` class.

Alternatively, you can write your own implementation of interface [Callback](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/util/Callback.html). The declaration of the method in that interface may look intimidating, but it really isn't that difficult to implement. And remember that the interface method is called by the *JavaFX* infrastructure. Your method is called with an argument that is an instance of your `Part` class and your method needs to return the appropriate [ObservableValue](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html) that you extract from the method argument.

Here is a small example program using your `Part` class that displays a table of parts. Note that it uses [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) that were added in Java 1.8. Also note, in the below code, that method [`getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html#getValue--) in class `CellDataFeatures` returns a `Part` object.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CellValueFactoryExample extends Application {
    private ObservableList<Part> items;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Part part = new Part(i, String.valueOf(i), (double) i, i, i, i);
            items.add(part);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Inventory");
        TableView<Part> table = createTable();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TableView<Part> createTable() {
        TableView<Part> table = new TableView<Part>(items);

        TableColumn<Part, Number> idCol = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(this::getIdColumnValue);

        TableColumn<Part, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(this::getNameColumnValue);

        TableColumn<Part, Number> priceCol = new TableColumn<>("Price");
        priceCol.setCellValueFactory(this::getPriceColumnValue);

        TableColumn<Part, Number> stockCol = new TableColumn<>("Stock");
        stockCol.setCellValueFactory(this::getStockColumnValue);

        TableColumn<Part, Number> minCol = new TableColumn<>("Min");
        minCol.setCellValueFactory(this::getMinColumnValue);

        TableColumn<Part, Number> maxCol = new TableColumn<>("Max");
        maxCol.setCellValueFactory(this::getMaxColumnValue);

        table.getColumns().addAll(idCol, nameCol, priceCol, stockCol, minCol, maxCol);
        return table;
    }

    private ObservableValue<Number> getIdColumnValue(CellDataFeatures<Part, Number> param) {
        return new SimpleIntegerProperty(param.getValue().getId());
    }

    private ObservableValue<String> getNameColumnValue(CellDataFeatures<Part, String> param) {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getName());
    }

    private ObservableValue<Number> getPriceColumnValue(CellDataFeatures<Part, Number> param) {
        return new SimpleDoubleProperty(param.getValue().getPrice());
    }

    private ObservableValue<Number> getStockColumnValue(CellDataFeatures<Part, Number> param) {
        return new SimpleIntegerProperty(param.getValue().getStock());
    }

    private ObservableValue<Number> getMinColumnValue(CellDataFeatures<Part, Number> param) {
        return new SimpleIntegerProperty(param.getValue().getMin());
    }

    private ObservableValue<Number> getMaxColumnValue(CellDataFeatures<Part, Number> param) {
        return new SimpleIntegerProperty(param.getValue().getMax());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is a screen-capture of the running app.

[image: inventor.png]